# Backuppc use smb

Tags: linux, backuppc

on linux server I use [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) and I want to do copys for windows clients. What lexic I should use?

i now are using and work good:

*.pl

```
$Conf{BackupFilesOnly} = {
  'C$' => [
    '/Testas'
  ]
};
$Conf{SmbSharePasswd} = '*****';
$Conf{SmbShareUserName} = 'EXAMPLE\\Administrator';
$Conf{XferMethod} = 'smb';
```

I want to do 150 clients copys to folder C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents.

*.pl

```
$Conf{BackupFilesOnly} = {
  'C$' => [
    '/Documents and Settings/username/My Documents'
  ]
};
$Conf{SmbSharePasswd} = '*****';
$Conf{SmbShareUserName} = 'EXAMPLE\\Administrator';
$Conf{XferMethod} = 'smb';
```

don't work. why? What lexic I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "username" as a variable in BackupFilesOnly, but you can use * like this:

```
$Conf{BackupFilesOnly} = {
  'C$' => [
    '/Documents and Settings/*/My Documents'
  ]
};
```

Please note that there has been a [bug in Debian Lenny's smbclient](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=519402) which prevented BackupPC from working with the "smb" XferMethod, so if you are indeed using a Debian or Ubuntu distribution and backing up a directory which is surely present, it might be worth looking into.

Comment: this script doesnt work. doesnt copy from windoes to linux "Documnetings and Settings/username/My Documents"

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are using Debian Lenny or an older Ubuntu release as your Linux distribution and may be affected by the quoted bug? Furthermore, please post a complete config and an XferLog / Errors log of the failing backup run.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier way would be to backup the whole drive and set the excludes to ignore what you don't want. That way you are not fighting by the limited smbclient file globbing for includes.

My answer to [smbclient NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED on directories when Windows doesn't](https://serverfault.com/questions/356105/smbclient-nt-status-access-denied-on-directories-when-windows-doesnt/388761#388761) will do almost all that you have asked with a little tweaking.